# Google maps styled marker z-index change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In [this](http://www.pdavis.nl/ShowSet7.php?Set=1) page I am trying to bring a clicked (styled) marker (or one selected using the vorige/volgende - previous/next - buttons) to the top by setting zIndex to google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1 (and restoring zIndex to the previous value upon another marker being clicked) using

```
  this.styleIcon.set('zIndex', google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
```

in the following code:

```
var thisMarker; 
var markers=[];  
var map;
var zoem=0;

function initialize() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
  var mapOptions = {center:new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeMid,longitudeMid),zoom:Zoom,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,streetViewControl:false,mapTypeControl:true,scaleControl:true,scaleControlOptions:{position:google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT}};
  map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  var i;
  var insertion;
  var previousMarker;
  var previousZindex;
  for (i = 0; i < fotoCount; i++)  { 
    var myLatLng =new google.maps.LatLng(Latituden[i], Longituden[i]); 
    var marker = new StyledMarker({styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,{color:'00ff00',text:Letters[i]}),position:myLatLng,map:map});
    marker.set('zIndex', -i);
    marker.myIndex = i;
    markers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      var insertion="";
      insertion='<img src=\"http://www.pdavis.nl/Ams/'.concat(Bestanden[this.myIndex],'.jpg\"></img>'); 
      insertion=insertion.concat('<table class=width100><tr><td>Bestand: ',Bestanden[this.myIndex],'</td><td class=pright>Lokatie: ',Latituden[this.myIndex],' °N., ',Longituden[this.myIndex],' °E. (',Letters[this.myIndex],')</td>');
      insertion=insertion.concat('<td class=pright>Genomen: ',Datums[this.myIndex],'</td></tr><td colspan=3>Object: ',Objecten[this.myIndex],'</td></table>');
      $('#photo').html(insertion);
      if(previousMarker!=null)
        {
        previousMarker.styleIcon.set('color', '00ff00');
        // -------------------------------------------- set zIndex
        previousMarker.styleIcon.set('zIndex', previousZindex);
        // -------------------------------------------------------
        }
      this.styleIcon.set('color', 'ff0000');
      this.styleIcon.set('zIndex', google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
      thisMarker=this.myIndex;
      if (zoem==1) //moet nu inzoemen
        {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Latituden[thisMarker], Longituden[thisMarker]));
        map.setZoom(18);
        }
      if (zoem==2) //moet nu uitzoemen
        {
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(latitudeMid,longitudeMid));
        map.setZoom(Zoom);
        zoem=0;
        }
      previousMarker=this;
      previousZindex=this.zIndex;
      });
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('volgende'), 'click', nextEvent);
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('vorige'), 'click', previousEvent);
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('zoemer'), 'click', zoemerEvent);
    }  
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[0], 'click');
}


function nextEvent() {
  thisMarker++;
  if (thisMarker>=fotoCount) {thisMarker=0};
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[thisMarker], 'click');
}

function previousEvent() {
  thisMarker--;
  if (thisMarker==-1) {thisMarker=fotoCount-1};
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[thisMarker], 'click');
}

function zoemerEvent() {
  if (zoemer.value == 'niet inzoemen op selectie') 
    {zoemer.value = 'inzoemen op selectie';
     zoem=2;}
  else
    {zoemer.value = 'niet inzoemen op selectie';
     zoem=1;}
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[thisMarker], 'click');
}
```

This does not work. I cannot find documentation of zIndex for styled markers, but assume this should be set analagous to setting colour (which does work for me).

Comment: What implementation of StyledMarker are you using? (Where did that library come from). Its documentation should indicate whether or not it supports a zIndex or not.  Or you could check the source code.

Comment: I use [link]https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/src/StyledMarker.js. I see no reference to zIndex in the source code, so I presume I cannon set zIndex here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by replacing (for example):

```
this.styleIcon.set('zIndex', google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
```

with

```
this.set('zIndex', google.maps.Marker.MAX_ZINDEX + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the zIndex directly in marker creation

```
var marker = new StyledMarker({styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,{zIndex: -1, color:'00ff00',text:Letters[i]}),position:myLatLng,map:map});
```